# How to wrap the text inside a RawChip?

Tags: flutter, flutter-chip

Currently I have painted me into a corner...

In Flutter I have following code snippet:

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
     children: [
       StreamBuilder(
         stream: globals.mWorkDatabase.getPictureFiles().watch(),
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
           if(snapshot.hasError){
             return Card(
               color: Colors.red,
               child: Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                 child: Text(
                   snapshot.error.toString(),
                   style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),),
               ),
             );
           }
           if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
             return const CircularProgressIndicator();
           }
           if(snapshot.hasData){
             var pictureFiles = snapshot.data as List<PictureFile?>?;
             if(pictureFiles?.isNotEmpty==true){
               return ListView.builder(
                   physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                   shrinkWrap: true,
                   reverse: true,
                   controller: ScrollController(),
                   itemCount: pictureFiles?.length,
                   itemBuilder: (context, index){
                     return Row(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                       children: [
                         Theme(
                           data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
                           child: RawChip( //<-- I want the text to wrap in RawChip !
                             backgroundColor: const Color(0x77FFFFFF),
                             label: Text("${pictureFiles?[index]?.filePath}"),
                             avatar: const Icon(Icons.image_outlined),
                             onDeleted: (){
                             },
                             onPressed: (){
                             },
                           ),
                         ),
                       ],
                     );
                   }
               );
             }
           }
           return const Card(
             child: Padding(
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
               child: Text("No pictures available..."),
             ),
           );
         }
       ),
     ],
   ),
 ),
```

The trouble is that the texts in the Chips are overflown, and I need to show the whole text inside the chip. Is it possible to let the text inside the Chip wrap ?

[image: The text inside the chips are overflown, I need it to wrap...]

Comment: have you tried wrapping the Text into the Row with expanded?

Comment: Yes, actually, it resulted into `RenderBox was not laid out` fails. I tried: `label: Row(
                                                      children: [
                                                        Expanded(child: Text("${pictureFiles?[index]?.filePath}")),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),`

and some other `Flexible`, and `Expanded` constellations...

Comment: There is also an OverflowBox() widget that you can wrap the Text() with it.

Comment: @CStark - naah, that didn't help either... it ran into "RenderBox was not laid out" error.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just have to wrap the `Theme` inside `Expanded`.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Expanded(           <--- Here wrap with Expanded
              child: Theme(
                data:
                    Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
                child: RawChip(
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0x77FFFFFF),
                  label: Text("yasd asdh ad ajsd ajhds a sd" * 2),
                  avatar: const Icon(Icons.image_outlined),
                  onDeleted: () {},
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Actually, the overflow error disappeared, but the fading inversed (!). The clue was to wrap the text, so the user see the enitre filename. I voted for you, that you found where the `Expanded` should be placed.

Comment: I think the inverse fading problem occured as a result that I have transparented the background, far more better with `label: Text("Looong text", overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis) `. Anyway, is the fact there that Chips can't be expanded in height ?

Comment: Yes, seems like the label in the RawChip can only have one line of text in Text Widget

Comment: May I make it horizontal scrollable ? and how ?